# Facebook sharing wrong characters

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, character-encoding, facebook-like

Please look at the result Facebook scrape my website:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.caominhblog.com%2F.

My website is http://www.caominhblog.com.

When I share it on Facebook, or share it via plugin, it always show these weird characters. It seems that Facebook debugger cannot read all of my header.

I can't find the solution for this.
Could you tell me how can I fix it?
Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution. It causes by W3 Total Cache - Disk Enhanced Mode. I simply turn it in to Basic Mode and everything work fine.

Best.